# Perform Drive API requests

Tags: dart, google-drive-api

I want to list the files contained in a specific folder.

I have to make 3 requests...

```dart
drive.files.list(q: "'root' in parents and title = '_folder_A'").then((storage.FileList list_0) {
  drive.files.list(q: "'${list_0.items[0].id}' in parents and title = '_folder_a'").then((storage.FileList list_1) {
    drive.files.list(q: "'${list_1.items[0].id}' in parents").then((storage.FileList list_3) {
        print(list_3.items[0].title); // The good file
    });
  });
});
```

Do you have a better proposition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Drive API doesn't natively support the ability to lookup folders or files by their path, resulting in the need to make multiple requests as you've demonstrated. Our recommended approach is to not base your code around paths, but instead folder or file IDs. Store the ID of the folder you are looking up and use it to search for files.